# Springboot Component returning properties values null

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I implemented this springboot Component that is supposed to return the value of some properties at runtime

```
@Component
public class ConnectionService {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("{spring.liquibase.change-log}")
    private String changelog;

    public ConnectionService() {

    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getChangelog() {
        return changelog;
    }

    public void setChangelog(String changelog) {
        this.changelog = changelog;
    }
}
```

But for some  reason all the properties are being returned as null

This is how I call my component

```
  @SpringBootApplication
public class MigrationsApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigrationsApplication.class);
    @Autowired
    static
    ConnectionService cs;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatabaseException {
          try{
                    cs=new ConnectionService();
                    String dbUrl=cs.getUrl();
                    logger.info("URL:"+dbUrl);
                    String dbUsername=cs.getUsername();
                    logger.info("USERNAME:"+dbUsername);
                    String dbPassword=cs.getPassword();
                    logger.info("PASSWORD:"+dbPassword);
                    String changelogPath=cs.getChangelog();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need a full constructor for the Component?It's because cs is static? Wasn't springboot meant to fill the values automatically?

Comment: Remove the `static` from both the method and the field. Then use a proper spring managed instance instead of calling a static method.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I should create a constructor, and instanciate a object of the component?

Comment: @M.Deinum edited my question

Comment: Autowiring won't work on statics. You are completly bypassing Spring as you are creating an instance yourself. You should let Spring create the instance and inject it.

Comment: @M.Deinum  sorry I am not understanding

Comment: @M.Deinum if I don't instanciate how can I get the url that I need to make a connection?

Comment: As stated you should use Spring. Just slapping a couple of annotations on a class won't do anything if you don't use the framework that does something with those annotations.

Comment: My problem is that I need to use it in my main class and it gets conflites because it's static

Comment: @M.Deinum I am starting to think that it's impossible to have access the values of the properties at the main class

Comment: No it isn't. As long as you use the proper techniques which you aren't.

Comment: I haver tried a lot of ways and always get stuck because of static

Comment: Because you shouldn't use static (the answer below shows you how to do it correctly).

Comment: But Main doesn't allow non static variables

Comment: Also why would you need those properties anyway? Those are standard spring boot properties and it looks like you are working around Spring Boot in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Component` means this is a bean, so Spring will handle its lifecycle. When the bean is created it will fill it with the requested data. However, you try to fill static values with it which is not a part of the lifecycle.
Add a full arg constructor to the class and let Spring inject it to the place where you want to use it and it will work fine.

Edit:

I just realized you not using static variables so the field injection should work when you properly let Spring to initialize your bean

Edit2:

Based on your snippet you using it wrong.
Do not put business logic into the main void, use `SpringApplication.run`, also, if you want a CLI then use Spring's CommandLineRunner interface like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MigrationsApplication.class implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigrationsApplication.class);
    
    @Autowired
    ConnectionService cs;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        String dbUrl=cs.getUrl();
        logger.info("URL:"+dbUrl);
        String dbUsername=cs.getUsername();
        logger.info("USERNAME:"+dbUsername);
        String dbPassword=cs.getPassword();
        logger.info("PASSWORD:"+dbPassword);
        String changelogPath=cs.getChangelog();
    }
}
```

Comment: why a full argument constructor? I don't know the value of the variabes so how will I sent it to the constructor?

Comment: It is called constructor injection https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Comment: tried the full argument constructor but it says "Could not autowire.No beans of type "String" found"

Comment: The problem is that I need the Properties on two methods that aren't inside the run method

Comment: Because the run method updates my database even when it's empty